# Converting datetime series.describe() output from nanoseconds to something legible

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas series `s_start` and `s_end` both of `datetime` `dtype` and are the same length. I calculate the difference between between each respective pair of elements by

```
time_range = s_end - s_start
```

And get a series `time_range` back which shows differences in days, hours, minutes, seconds etc...

Then I take this series and do:

```
time_range.describe()
```

All the stats come back in nanoseconds - is there any way to show this in days, hours, mins, sec etc.? I find it hard to understand nanoseconds...

Comment: This would make a good enhancement request on github: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

Comment: Thanks Andy - does this mean that there is no easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the datetime objects to date objects like so

```
In [26]: s = Series(date_range('1/1/2001', '1/1/2002'))

In [27]: def try_convert_date(obj):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         return obj.date()
    ...:     except AttributeError:
    ...:         return obj
    ...:     

In [28]: s.describe().map(try_convert_date)
Out[28]: 
count            366
unique           366
first     2001-01-01
last      2002-01-01
top       2001-01-01
freq               1
dtype: object
```